# How to use find and the prune option with an while loop

Tags: regex, while-loop, find, rename, pruning

i've got an question about find, prune and print combined with an while loop. I want find every file named *trace* but not the files ending on *mailed*. Also i want to exclude the files in the *lost+found* directory. My idea was to use the following command:

`find /opt/myTESTdir/ -iwholename '*lost+found' -prune -o -ctime +4 -type f -iname "*trace*" -not -iname "*.mailed*" -print0 | while read file ; do newfile=${file%.txt}".mailed" ; mv -v $file $newfile ; done`

My question is now should this work or is there an syntax error? I've tried out the find command without everything behind the pipe and it seems, that's work correctly. But i'm not sure about the combination. I hope you could answer me :)

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: At the very least, you cannot mix `-print0` with a regular `read` which expects newline-terminated input, not zero-terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In while loop, it seems you are trying to rename files with extension `.txt` to `.mailed`. You can achieve the same using `-exec` option.

Try adding following portion to the end of your find command and remove piping to while loop.

```
-exec sh -c 'mv -f $0 ${0%.txt}.mailed' {} \;
```

Complete command would look like

```
find /opt/myTESTdir/ -iwholename '*lost+found' -prune -o -ctime +4 -type f -iname '*trace*' ! -iname '*.mailed*' -exec sh -c 'mv -f $0 ${0%.txt}.mailed' {} \;
```

Comment: Did i need therefore also the `-print0` option?

Comment: @Marcusg562 No, you don't need it. I've updated ans with full command.